# Mongodb Morphia aggregation lookup match

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup, morphia

I have a lookup issue using Morphia.
Here is my code :

```
class person{
private ObjectId id;
private String name;
}

class book{
private ObjectId id;
private String title;
}

class person_ownership{
private ObjectId id;
private person p;
private List<book> books;
}

List<book> BOOKs = new ArrayList<book>();
```

What i trying is by searching on person collection to filter with the ids from book collection

Here is my aggregation pipeline

```
AggregationPipeline aggr = DS.createAggregation(person.class);
aggr.lookup("person_ownership", "id", "p.id", "ownership");
aggr.unwind("ownership");

Query<person> q = DS.createQuery(person.class);
q.disableValidation().criteria("ownership.books").in(BOOKs);
aggr.match(q );

Iterator<person> aggregate = aggr.aggregate(person.class, opts);
```

I had to **q.disableValidation()** for it to pass. but the pipe still return nothing.

**And i have to query this by passing throu person !!!**

is that even possible ? there is no exemple out there !!!

Comment: It is possible. Can you add the document from each of the collection that you are trying to query ?

Comment: persons :[{_id : ... ,name : ...}] ; 

person_ownerships : [{_id : ..., p : DBRef("persons", ObjectId("...")),  books : [ DBRef("books", ObjectId("...")) ,  DBRef("books", ObjectId("...")) , ...]} ] ;
books : [ {_id : ... , title : "..."}]

Comment: books : [ {_id : ... , title : "..."} , ...]

Do we always have to **out** put this into a new collection ? 
If so what happens for concurrents requests ?
I tried to **aggr.unwind("ownership.books");** aswell but still get non correct results

Comment: Your classes should be Pascal-case, not lowercase as you have them here.

Answer (score 0):

Seems Like this is not Possible !!! 
Morphia does not lookup on reference Fields. 
I had to inster another field referencing the person Id for the aggregation to work !!!